# Disallow users to use a certain page when signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have 2 pages. 1 for signed out users who come on the site called `welcome` and another for signed in users called `home`:

Here are my routes:

```
namespace :user do
   root :to => "home#index"
end

root :to => "pages#welcome"

match '/welcome',  :to => 'pages#welcome'
match '/home',     :to => 'home#index'
```

I use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` for my `HomeController` so they land on the `welcome` page if signed out.

How can I make so Signed in user cannot access the welcome page?

### Answer

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
    @title = "Welcome"
    if signed_in?
    redirect_to home_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "welcome" action, just redirect them to the "home" action if they're signed in. ie redirect both ways, depending on signed-in-edness :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't match routes like that.  Duplicate of [ROR 3 conditions in routes.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690063/ror-3-conditions-in-routes-rb)

You should match '/' to one controller action and then redirect or render different content based on whether the user is logged in.